# Where is define description method in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop

Good morning,

When I change language in the front of my shop, for example from Polish to English everything is fine. Everything without description. The description is always in Polish language. I want to check what is wrong so I run the debug mode in IDE.
In ProductController I have this:

```
$this->product->description = $this->transformDescriptionWithImg($this->product->description);
```

However I dont see where

```
$this->product->description
```

is define. I expected a database query and maybe a problem with id_lang or something like this. How to debug this variable correctly ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Is not easy to debug without an error, but you can reduce the possibilities.

**There are only 3 possible things that can cause the problem:**

1. You have forgot to write the english description in the product editor.
2. The native behavior has been altered by modifications in core files or override files.
3. For some module that is modifying the Product object or the smarty variable that contains the product.

**How to check?**

1. Go to the product in the catalog of products and be sure it contains the english description.
2. Restore to the original core files or by disable the override files in the performance tab.
3. If you have not modified the native modules, disable the custom modules in the performance tab.

Comment: I did it before I write a post.

Comment: Is that it simply can not be something else, by default the platform works perfectly, so it had to have been modified in the core files or by override file or it’s a module.